# boto3 django transfer.upload_file is breaking image, incomplete transfer

Tags: python, django, file-upload, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 library for transferring user uploaded image on my web application to S3 bucket, i am using transfer.upload_file but strangely part of the image gets vanished in uploaded file, though file seems perfect on instance but not in S3 bucket, any help would be really great.

I am uploading file to local server via :

```
fpath = settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/temp/' + self.fileObj.name
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(fpath) newName = Encrypt(str(int(time.time())) + filename).encrypt() + file_extension 
destination = open(fpath, 'wb+')
for chunk in self.fileObj.chunks(): 
     destination.write(chunk)
```

then to s3 via client

```
 boto3.client('s3',S3_REGION) transfer = S3Transfer(client) 
 transfer.upload_file( fpath, S3_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,self.folder+'/'+newName, extra_args={'ACL': 'public-read', 'ContentType':mime_type} )
```

Comment: can you provide more details and some code? at least some ideas what can be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I am uploading file to local server via :                                                        fpath = settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/temp/' + self.fileObj.name
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(fpath)
        newName = Encrypt(str(int(time.time())) + filename).encrypt() + file_extension
        destination = open(fpath, 'wb+')
        for chunk in self.fileObj.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

Comment: then to s3 via                                                                                    client = boto3.client('s3',S3_REGION)
        transfer = S3Transfer(client)
        #transfer = boto3.s3.transfer(client)
        # Upload /tmp/myfile to s3://bucket/key
        transfer.upload_file(
            fpath,
            S3_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            self.folder+'/'+newName,
            extra_args={'ACL': 'public-read', 'ContentType':mime_type}
        )

Comment: file at local server seems fine.. but on s3 image is incomplete...

Comment: just edit your question and post this code there. It will be more readable and other will be able to go through it.

Comment: updated question...

Comment: there is code sample option in editor, please use it to format the code. it will be readable